# Keras: Combine multiple matrix-like inputs of different sizes

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

To train my neural network I want to use two different inputs, that are matrix-like (bathymetry and a spectral wave-energy density matrix) of shapes (160, 160) and (32, 24).

Normally I only have one input of shape (160, 160) and found a network architecture that worked well with it.

My idea for the two inputs above was to somehow upsample the (32, 24) matrix, concatenate both matrices and pass it to the rest of the neural network as before. However, I am not quite sure what the most efficient/elegant way is.

I tried two approaches, in the first one I "upsample" the matrix by simply using two dense layers, like in the following:

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Concatenate
 
inp_bathy = Input(shape=(160, 160, 1))
inp_spec = Input(shape=(32, 24, 1))

flat_spec = Flatten()(inp_spec)
flat_spec = Dense(32*24, activation='relu')(flat_spec)
flat_spec = Dense(160*160, activation='relu')(flat_spec)

spec = Reshape((160, 160, 1))(flat_spec)
input_mat = Concatenate()([spec, inp_bathy])

# ... model continues here
```

The performance is actually quite good with this approach, the only minor problem being that the number of parameters shoots up by more than 1 million (in contrast to around 150,000 parameters of the rest of the architecture).

I wondered, if I could implement something similar with convolutional layers:

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2DTranspose, Concatenate

inp_bathy = Input(shape=(160, 160, 1))
inp_spec = Input(shape=(32, 24, 1))

spec = Conv2DTranspose(32, (5, 7), strides=(5, 2),
                       activation='relu')(inp_spec)
spec = Conv2DTranspose(1, (1, 4), strides=(1, 3),
                       activation='relu')(spec)

input_mat = Concatenate()([spec, inp_bathy])

# ... model continues here
```

However, this doesn't seem very elegant and the non-square kernels and unequal strides likely influence the performance (it performs considerably worse than the previous method).

Is there maybe a more "standard" way of dealing with such a problem in keras/tensorflow? Or possibly one that does not require as many parameters as the first approach?

Comment: Why don't you use the ImageDataGenerator function to load your data, that way you can resize your images, check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

Comment: @GautamChettiar Hi, Gautam, thanks for your answer! The problem in my case is that I'm not working with classical image data that I can resize. The inputs are direct results from a numerical simulation, so I feel like simply resizing the input would distort the data. I'll edit the question title to make it clearer.